# How can I get the text from EditText of a recyclerview item when user clicks on a button of the same item?

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, onclicklistener

I am designing a RecyclerView list. Each item of the Recyclerview contains a LinearLayout. This LinearLayout contains two views, the first one is an EditText and the second one is Button. When user taps on the button, it fires an onclick event. From onClick listener, I need to get the content of the EditText. I don't find a way to access the content of a sibling view when the user taps on another sibling view.

My question is not "how can I set on click listener to a button inside adapter". Most of the people answered how to set onClick listener to a button which is there inside the recyclerview item. My question is bit different, when I am inside onClick method which is fired from button, how will I access the edittext which is a sibling of button. Every item has one edittext, so when I click on a button how will I find the correct edittext?

For example, I have a recylerview of size 10. And each item of recyclerview contains a LinearLayout and inside linearlayout two item, one is an Edittext and the other one is a Button. when I tap on 7th items button, how will I get the text of 7th item's Edittext? I hope I have explained it well

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please provide any code you have tried.

Comment: I have resolved it with the help of view.getParent() method.          
            LinearLayout parent = (LinearLayout)v.getParent();
                    EditText passwordView = null;
                    for(int i = 0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++){
                        if(parent.getChildAt(i)instanceof EditText){
                            passwordView = (EditText)parent.getChildAt(i);
                        }
                    }

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of, you need two references: one to your `EditText` and one to your `Button`. You can get those in your `ViewHolder`. Next, you need an `OnClickListener`. The ViewHolder can conveniently also implement one but you could also use `onBindViewHolder()` for that.

Inside that OnClickListener you can filter out your id with a switch statement if you want to and then get the content of the EditText like this:

```
switch(viewId) {
    case R.id.buttonId:
        String text = editText.getText().toString();
        // do something with that text
        return true;
}
```

In case you implemented an OnClickListener in your ViewHolder you can then do this `button.setOnClickListener(this);` inside your ViewHolder to make sure `onClick()` is actually called when you click the button.

**EDIT:**
Here's some sample code that should work for your case. I'm implementing View.OnClickListener here as mentioned above.

```
public class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {

    EditText editText;
    Button button;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView) {
        super(itemView);

        editText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.editText);
        button = itemView.findViewById(R.id.button);
        button.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {
        switch(view.getId()) {
            case R.id.button:
                String text = editText.getText().toString();
                break;
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it would look like if you were to do it in your `onBindViewHolder()` (in this case you would **NOT** implement the OnClickListener in your ViewHolder obviously):

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final ViewHolder holder, int position) {
    holder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            String text = holder.editText.getText().toString();
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: How will I identify the correct EditText inside onClick method? It will send only the view details of clicked button!

Comment: Yes, it will. But when you put your OnClickListener inside the ViewHolder you've already got the reference to the correct EditText and Button (obviously) because you're in the ViewHolder class.
If you put the OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder(); the method passes you an instance of the ViewHolder (I think?) or a position in your data set. With this you can also get a reference to the correct views.

Comment: Can share some code which you believe will work? I am not getting your answer !!

Comment: I've now added some sample code, both with implementing OnClickListener in the ViewHolder and with adding the OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder()

Comment: Thank you. Implementing onClick inside onBindViewHolder resolved this. However, I would rather keep my all click listeners at one place. So I chose adding click listener inside my view holder itself. And when I receive the listener callback I took the parent and through parent i accessed second child. that way I reduced the mess. Your answer is perfect. Thanks once again for your time Mr..

Comment: No problem, glad I could help you out!

Answer (score 0):

You can use holder pattern for RecylcerView adapter. Then you can set click listener on your button and get the text from EditText.

```
public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

private EditText simpleEditText;
private Button simpleButton;

public SimpleViewHolder(final View itemView) {

    super(itemView);
    simpleEditText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.simple_edit_text);
    simpleButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.simple_button);

    simpleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            String text = simpleEditText.getText().toString()
        }
    });
   }
}
```

Comment: I have used the holder and received onClick event. But, onClick gives only the information about the clicked view. It is not giving a way to access it's sibling view. EditText is a sibling of Button

Comment: Are they in the same row? If button and edit text are in the same row. You can use this code snippet.

Comment: I tried this but the edittext is not valid inside onclick listener since onclick is a callback type of function

Comment: Your code looks OK. What do you mean by "edittext is not valid inside onclick listener"?

Answer (score 0):

Step 1 :Make an abstract function in your adapter.

```
abstract void onButtonClicked(String text);
```

Step 2: Declare your adapter Abstract.

Step 3: Override the method (onButtonClicked(String text);) in your activity were you have instantiated the adapter.

Step 4: In your adapter inside the onClickListener for your button call the function :

```
onButtonClicked(editText.getText().toString());
```

and you'll get the string in your activity where you overrided the method.

Comment: You have to initialize your edit text in your adapter inside the ViewHolder class just like you did with the button.
Please share the code so that we can understand it more precisely

Comment: But, still the correct instance of edittext can't access inside onClick. This is a callback type function and the instance of edittext is available outside.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it inside your adapter which is being set on the recycler view.

```js
 public class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public ImageView mImageView;

        public MyViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            mImageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.imageView);

        }
    }
```

And in the bindview holder you can access the views

```js
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ImageAdapter.MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
      holder.mImageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
             //Your Code to access the edit text content
            }
        });
    }
```

Comment: How can I pass the sibling view to onClick?

Comment: You are trying to access the data in the wrong place a access it when the view has been binded in OnBindViewHolder

Comment: The code which is added was suggested by somebody from the same page and that was added just for reference to understand what I need to do. You will face the same kind of problem even when you use it from holder part. I have modified my question to make the question more clear. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Simply Use Your `ViewHolder`. It contains all the children you want. Implement the code inside your adapter where each item is inflated. Here is an example.

```
//inside the onBindViewHolder
viewHolder.button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    String text = viewHolder.editText.getText().toString();
                    Log.d("output", text);
                }
            });
```

If you are using `FirebaseUI` Implement this inside the `populateViewHolder` for older version and `onBindViewHolder` for the later versions.

Answer (score 0):

use a custom listener like this in the holder:

```
    public class SimpleViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
 private EditText simpleEditText;  
private Button simpleButton;  
public SimpleViewHolder(final View itemView, final OnItemSelectedListener listener) {  
super(itemView);  
simpleEditText = (EditText) itemView.findViewById(R.id.simple_edit_text);  
simpleButton = (Button) itemView.findViewById(R.id.simple_button); 
 simpleButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {  
@Override public void onClick(View v) {  
String text = simpleEditText.getText().toString();
 if(listener != null) listener.onItemSelected(text);
  }
  });
  }

    public interface OnItemSelectedListener{ 
void onItemSelected(String value);
 }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

People put -1 when they don't know the answer or when they do not understand question. So funny!! In onclick I took parent(getParent()) from the view and accessed the second child of the parent. With that I am able to access the content of the sibling.

```
                    ` public void onClick(View v) {
                          for(int i = 0;i<parent.getChildCount();i++){
                               if(parent.getChildAt(i)instanceof EditText){
                                  passwordView = (EditText)parent.getChildAt(i);
                                }
                           }
                      }`
```